# How to add include in Generic repository pattern in Ef Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, db-first

Net core and efcore db first approach. I have two tables. First table is SiteDetails and it contains Sitedetails related columns and it references other table countries based on primary key and foreign key relationships. Now I want to include these countries also as part of result. Below is my generic method.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

In below code I am calling above method

```
 var siteDetails= await this.siteDetailsRepository.GetAsync(x => x.siteNo== siteNo , source => source.Include(???)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Below is the relationship between siteDetails page Country Table
SitDetails has fields siteNo, siteName, CountryId
Country has fields CountryId and CountryName

Can someone help me to write include syntax here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use GenericRepository you should declare Type when Initializing. if you don't initilize GenericRepository with Explicit Type (like SiteDetail) this is Initializing in your example:

```
public class SiteDetailService : ISiteService 
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository<SiteDetail> _siteDetailRepository;
    public SiteDetailService(IBaseRepository<SiteDetail> siteDetailsRepository)
    {
        _siteDetailRepository = siteDetailsRepository;
    }
}
```

and you can call your repository methods with defined Type:

```
   var siteDetails = 
           await this._siteDetailsRepository
                     .GetAsync(x => 
                               x.siteNo == siteNo,  //Conditions         
                               null,                //Orders          
                               x => x.Country)      //Includes
           .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I need. Also if I want orderby then x=>x.feildname I need to send right

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> GetAsync(
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
    {
        return await includes
          .Aggregate(_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable(),
              (entity, property) => entity.Include(property))
          .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Usually code only answers can be improved by some explanation of why or when you should do that. Other thing to consider is that the OP Question already has an accepted answer, and this diminishes the odd for yours to be noted and upvoted.

Comment: Well, it is just another way to do it. I don't care If get noted or upvoted. I am not sure what is your purpose though :)